# How can I filter between a range of numbers and hide rows that aren't in the range using DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to take input through two input fields. A minimum field and a maximum field. With the minimum and maximum values I want to look at a certain column and check to see if the value of the cell in that column is between the range. If the cell is not in the range of the minimum and maximum values, I would like to hide the row.

Here's is what I've been working with: (Currently not working as intended.)

```js
$('table').DataTable();

var counterLow = $('#counter-low'),
    counterHigh = $('#counter-high');

function filterAge() {
    table.columns(1).every(function () {
        var min = +counterLow.val(),
            max = +counterHigh.val();

        this.data().each(function (data, index) {
            if (data > min && data < max) {
                table.row(index).child.show();
            } else {
                table.row(index).child.hide();
            }
        });
    });
}
counterLow.on('keyup', filterAge);
counterHigh.on('keyup', filterAge);
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th, table td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<input id="counter-low" type="text" placeholder="Minimum age" />
<input id="counter-high" type="text" placeholder="Maximum age" />
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Jon</td>
            <td>64</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bill</td>
            <td>86</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Joel</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fred</td>
            <td>35</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one
***Updated**

```
var table = $('table').DataTable();
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
    return parseInt(data[1]) >= parseInt($('#counter-low').val() || data[1]) 
        && parseInt(data[1]) <= parseInt($('#counter-high').val() || data[1])
});
$('#counter-low, #counter-high').on('keyup', table.draw);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y8n0wLj/1/)**

Comment: This will work, however it won't be tied in with the plugin. I'm hoping to utilize what's in the plugin so it fires the correct events, etc. (e.g. if no results are found, the plugin will throw up a "no results" message, where as if I just hide and show the table rows, it doesn't know what is visible, or invisible inside the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I was able to obtain what was needed with a custom filter. This is what I used.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        var min = +counterLow.val() || table.column(1).data().sort()[0],
            max = +counterHigh.val() || table.column(1).data().sort().reverse()[0],
            age = +aData[1];

        return !!(age >= min && age <= max) &&
               !(isNaN(min) || isNaN(max) || isNaN(age));
    }
);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0dyxysLv/)

Comment: looks like you are using `old dataTables (1.9) api`. check my updated answer

Comment: @Dennis Martinez This is good. But you can't avoid hiding the "Show entries" and "Search box" at the top.