# Filter between range of numbers to hide table rows (HTML, javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

**Question**

How can i filter the rows of a HTML table using javascript to only show rows where the column value is within an input range.

**Table (PHP, HTML)**

I have a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyMvQ.png) with values taken from a SQL database ([SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sngju1uUBNMF56eVVTYu6H/8)) using the following PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, price, id, mark, value, url FROM cpu";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table id='myTable'><tr><th>CPU</th><th>Price</th><th>Mark</th><th>Value</th><th>Image</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td><a href='https://au.pcpartpicker.com/product/".$row["id"]."' target='_blank'>" . $row["name"]. "</a></td><td>" . $row["price"]."</td><td>" . $row["mark"]."</td><td>" . $row["value"]."</td><td><img src=". $row["url"]." height='42' width='42'></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

**Input (HTML)**

On the web page I also have two HTML input boxes, one for search and one for price:

```
<input type="number" id="myPrice" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Enter amount.." title="Type in a amount" min="0">
<input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for cpus.." title="Type in a cpu name">
```

**Search filtering (JavaScript)**

For search filtering I use the following javascript code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

However I am unsure of the code I should use for myPrice. I believe that first I must convert the price column to a string then perform the filter.  I am unsure of the exact code but managed to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973625/how-can-i-filter-between-a-range-of-numbers-and-hide-rows-that-arent-in-the-ran) that seemed similar.

I'm new and I know I don't have much code but if you could even just point me in the right direction that would be great.

**Update:**

I think this code will convert the price to a float by removing the "$" and converting it to a float, am i correct in thinking this?

```
var price = str.slice(1,5);
var price = parseFloat(price)
```

**Update 2:**

```
function myPriceFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myPrice");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    td = td.slice(1,5);
    td = parseFloat(td)
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

I think i need to create 2 variables for 10% above and below input then check if td is within input?

**Update 3:**

```
function myPriceFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myPrice");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  priceLow = input * 0.9
  priceHigh = input * 1.1
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    td = td.slice(1,5);
    td = parseFloat(td)
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > priceLow and txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) < priceHigh ) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

This is all the code i think i need however it isn't working possible things could be the handling of td as text not float but I'm not sure. If anyone is able to provide any insight that would be great.

If you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks

Comment: I would probably use AJAX, search the DB, then re-populate the DOM with the found data.

Comment: Going to honest not really sure how to do that.

Comment: Please see update